# SonarQube Custom Webservice

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have build custom web service to record event change that SonarQube did not provide. I am implementing web service using `org.sonar.api.server.ws.WebService` as an Extension Point and injecting the extension by implementing Plugin. I need the webservice to read all user request. Is it right to use Plugin as entry point? Is it even possible to do that?

**Note:** I am using SonarQube 6.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading sonar source for days, i do that by extending to `org.sonar.api.web.ServletFilter`. So in sonar there is class called `org.sonar.server.platform.web.MasterServletFilter`, this class call all filter of ServletFilter. MasterServletFilter implements doFilter method from `javax.servlet.Filter`. In that method they do something with request and response, and finally continuing FilterChain. All i do is implements doFilter too.

So i am not using web service as extension point, instead i used ServletFilter. But still use Plugin as entry point.